# How to attach Intellij Idea 15 Community Edition to GWT Project 1.5 with hosted mode?

Tags: java, debugging, gwt, intellij-idea, ant

I need use Intellij Idea 15 Community Edition with GWT Hosted Mode. I want to use debugger and want to read logs from server side and client side. 
Now I use 2 ant targets:

1. compile all java sources to class-files and after that compile java class files to js through GWTCompiler.
2. start tomcat with compiled sources work directory.

Unfortunately, I can't use Ultimate Edition, and I shouldn't do that: if it was so, this question would not to be there.
Anybody have at least some ideas?

Comment: 1) Why is your Intellij so old? 2) Why is your GWT so old? The main problem you're going to have is with GWT 1.5 - GWT stopped supporting dev mode with GWT 2.6 (I think), so IDEs followed suit.

Comment: 1) 15 version - it is not very old. It is prev-last stable version.
2) It is old project, and other teammates uses Eclipse with preferences and Eclipse work fine, but I like Idea and preference Idea as my favorite IDE.

Comment: From _last year_. 8 months is a long time in computing...

Comment: Hey, In this project not me determine technologies in project and jdk version, and it is ass pain but I can only quit from this job. Instead of to goof to me cam you gave nice advice?